# Why is bismuthine (BiH3, or bismuth trihydride) unstable if bismuth is considered to be the most stable heavy element?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, metal

Bismuth-209 is considered to be the most stable heavy element, though it is weakly radioactive.

Given that, why does bismuthine ($\ce{BiH3}$, or bismuth trihydride) have a half-life of only 20 minutes and is the least stable hydride in its group?

Comment: The reactivity of bismuthane is not related to the stability of isotopes. Compare the reactivity of $\ce{CH4}$ with that of $\ce{GeH4}$.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it relates stabilities of isotopes with reactivities of hydrogen compounds.

Comment: I object. A confusion between two ideas, one of which belongs to chemistry, is by extension related to chemistry as well.

Comment: I think it should stay open. While the basis of the question is wrong, I could imagine other students having a similar question and those who find the SE, could learn from it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By putting words in incorrect order it is quite easy to arrive at nonsense. Bismuth is by far not the ***most stable heavy element***; indeed, it is not particularly stable at all. Instead, it is the ***most heavy stable element*** (if we disregard its radioactivity, that is). Think of these two definitions for a while. Think how different they are.

Moreover, this is about nuclear stability, which has **absolutely** nothing to do with chemical stability of the element, which in turn (besides not being well defined) has nothing to do whatsoever with stability of its hydride.

I sincerely recommend to all chemistry students to abandon using the word "stability" altogether, for it seems to cause a great deal of confusion every single time someone uses it.

Answer (score 1):

$\ce{BiH3}$ is unstable due to the large size of central atom & therefore its tendency to form stable covalent bond with small hydrogen atom decreases, as a result the bond strength decreases